# Dell Compellent clock skew too great

Tags: storage, dell, ntp

I received this alert from our Dell Compellent SC200:
"
Alert created on controller '12345' for object [internal ref: 'Global '] - [ProgressionTime]: Some Data Progression features, such as RAID Rebalance, may not run properly because the controller's clock skew is too great. Configure time settings to resolve.
"

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXcie.png)

In the "Unisphere for SC Series" web interface, I found the "Time Settings" section where I can change the ntp server:

[time settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwjBS.png)

For those who have resolved this error before:

1. Is this the correct setting to address the issue?
2. Will updating the ntp server incur any downtime?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Select Use NTP Server, and enter the DNS name of your NTP server.  Every network should have several of these, use the same configuration as on servers.

Read the documentation for whether this can be done online. I assume yes it can, block storage as a protocol does not really care about the time on the management hosts.